# Dragging new link to an already linked node input doesn't delete the existing link: it switches it to the next input instead. How to avoid that?

Tags: node-editor, interface

Blender seems to have this default behavior when editing node trees:

If I have a node with an input that is already receiving a link, and I drag another link to that input, the existing link isn't replaced with the new one: its end gets *displaced* to the next unoccupied input (if any), instead.

[image]

This, at best, forces me to manually unhook or cut the displaced link to eliminate it before or after the intended operation. At worst, I can completely miss that it happened and so introduce a "bug" in the node tree.

I've tried disabling some usual suspects (Nodewrangler, etc.), but none of them seem to be producing this functionality, and I'm not finding anything about it in Blender's documentation.

So, my question is: is there any preferences setting, keyboard shortcut or other methods to avoid this behavior and effect a link replacement instead of a displacement?

Comment: This is native functionality, not part of any addon, as far as I know can't be toggled off unfortunately, other than changing source code compiling it yourself

Comment: Digging into the matter, I'm discovering that this behavior seems to be type of node-dependent. For example:  
  
* When working with a Bright Contrast node, the new link fully replaces the existing one.  
  
* When Working with a Principled BSDF node, the existing link jumps to a different, not necessarily consecutive input.  
  
So, it seems the behavior has different settings at the type of node level.

Comment: It's even more complicated than that: in the case of the Principled BSDF node, the existing link often replaces the previous one in certain inputs, but in others it can make it jump to a different, not necessarily consecutive input, if it is related somehow: for example, from SS IOR to SS.  
This is a rather confusing behavior, conducive to producing inadvertent mistakes if one is being fast at editing a node tree.

Comment: Blender does this for "similar" or equivalent input sockets, which either have the same data type or at least are part of a series of sequential inputs. Real world results from the user standpoint may not be as predictable as one would desire.

Comment: To add to the previous mentioned things: this sometimes can even be desired behaviour, for example if you coincidently plug in values in the wrong order for e.g. subtraction or division. If you plug the first value in the wrong socket, it's not necessary to unplug it and do it again, just plug the correct one in afterwards and the other switches automatically. Or if you plugged shaders in the wrong order in a _Mix Shader_ or colors/textures in a _Mix RGB_...

Comment: I'm posting a petition to make this behavior optional, at the Preferences or keyboard shortcuts level. I guess it won't have much traction, but…  Thank you all for your comments . https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/4zJg/